# How to resolve the error 'fe_sendauth: no password supplied' in Rails using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3

I've tried to create my Rails app with postgresql database, but when I started `rails server`, I got this error:

> fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Here're my actions step by step:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
$ gem install pg
$ rails new timetracker --database=postgresql --skip-unit-test
```

My `database.yml` file looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password:

development:
  <<: *default
  database: timetracker_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: timetracker_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: timetracker_production
```

And here's my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# modified by me.
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

So, when I do `rails server` I get the error and then here's what I get by doing this:

```
$ rails c
$ ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get(:@config)
```

> 2.1.5 :001 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get(:@config)
>   PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
>
> from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `initialize'  from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in`new'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `connect'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in`initialize'  from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in
>   `new'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in`
>   postgresql_connection'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in
>   `new_connection'  from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in`
>   checkout_new_connection'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in
>   `acquire_connection'  from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in`
>   block in checkout'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in`
>   checkout'    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in
>   `block in connection'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in`
>   mon_synchronize'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in
>   `connection'  from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in`
>   retrieve_connection' ... 4 levels...     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in
>   `start'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in`
>   console'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in
>   `run_command!'    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`
>   '    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'     from /home/denis/WEB/Rails/timetracker/bin/rails:8:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`load'    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`load_dependency'     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'   from -e:1:in`'2.1.5 :002 >

I'm using postgresql for the first time and I guess I'm just doing something wrong.

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Move your amendments to `pg_hba.conf` above the pre-supplied ones. Also you have a duplicate entry.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Unfortunately, this didn't change anything. Still getting the same error...

Comment: Also do `sudo service postgresql reload` or reboot to load the changes

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, thanks, I guess it worked, but I started to get the new error: `FATAL: database "timetracker_development" does not exist`. Should I actually create all the databases manually (I thought rails would do that for me) ?

Comment: Probably. Not familiar with rails, but most ORMs I've seen only create tables and such, not the actual databases.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Tried to create the database manually and everything worked fine! Your answers have been really helpful. 
PS: you may want to post your answers as the actual answer and I'll tick it as the accepted one

Comment: I know this is a year late, but for posterity, after getting `FATAL: database "database_name" does not exist`, try running `rake db:create:all`. If _that_ doesn't work (i.e. you have insufficient permissions), try following the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116927/postgres-permission-denied-to-create-database-on-rake-dbcreateall).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to remove `host: localhost` from the `default:` group.

Comment: The reason why this works is that without defined `host`  Unix socket is used. During authentication it will match `peer` rule in `pg_hba.conf`, thus no password is needed (your username `whoami` must match a role in DB).

Answer (score 11):

PostgreSQL matches `pg_hba.conf` entries in the order they are specified, so it uses the pre-specified `host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5` entry for authentication instead of your specified `trust` entry.

Move your custom `trust` entries above the pre-specified ones (and optionally comment out the old ones) and then reload your configuration by running `sudo service postgresql reload` (on Ubuntu) or rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but for me, this line did not solve the problem

```
host    mydb       myuser         127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

while this one did :

```
host    mydb       myuser         localhost               trust
```