# NoDatabaseError when running Ruby Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu version 15.10. After I type `rails s` in the terminal to start a Ruby app and navigate to `0.0.0.0:3000`, I get the following error on the web page:

> ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError at /
>
> FATAL:  database "local-election_development" does not exist
>   Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database

When I type `bin/rake db:create db:migrate` from the terminal, I get this error:

> PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116927/postgres-permission-denied-to-create-database-on-rake-dbcreateall), but I did not know how to execute the command `ALTER USER new_user CREATEDB;`.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into the postgres user:

```
su - postgres
```

Log into by typing:

```
psql
```

You should now see a prompt for ***postgres=#***

Comment: After typing `psql`, it asks for a password. If I forgot it, how can I reset it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation this answer will help you

Answer (score 2):

You can to enter the SQL command on the PostgreSQL console, which can be invoked with `psql`.

If it complains that the database does not exist, then use `createdb`, if the user doesn't exist, use `createuser`. Search for PostgreSQL-related questions if you have an issue with any of these.

Comment: After typing psql, it asks for a password. If I forgot it, how can I reset it?

Comment: Try [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation) or [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=reset+postgres+password)