# Sqlite to Postgres - existing Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

I'm new to Rails.

I already have a project ready to be deployed.

I'm using Sqlite3 but I want to switch to Postgres.

I follow many tutorials but nothing works, so I need your help.

When I follow instructions from Railscast, it doesn't work : [http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast][1]

When I run :

```
rake db:migrate
```

it return :

```
rake aborted! ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "development" does not exis
```

When I run.. :

```
$ taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 User password
```

..with the User I set up in database.yml,

I set "SECRET_KEY_BASE=mypassword" into .env.development fil.

Here is my database.yml :

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: development
  pool: 5
  username: FC
  password: 

test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: test
  pool: 5
  username: FC
  password:
```

it return :

```
/Users/fc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions (LoadError)
    from /Users/fc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/fc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from /Users/fc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

PG version :

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.4
```

which psql :

```
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

I'm lost at this point because nothing works.

**How can I do the migration easily, step by step ?**

Comment: to solve `database "development" does not exist` run `rake db:create` first then migrate

Comment: How "rake db:create" could know that I need to create "development database" ? And why do I have to create a DB even I already have from sqlite3 ? I just want to migrate sqlite db to postgres.

Comment: you said you are moving from sqlite to postgres so you need to create database in `postgres` first and then migrate and it will know that it needs to create development data base since in database.yml you have mentioned `database: development` and regarding keeping the data, you need to feed the sqlite dump to `psql`

Comment: When I run rake db:create it returns : PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database : CREATE DATABASE "development" ENCODING = 'utf8'

Comment: That means your postgres user `FC` dont have privilege to create database. check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31669921/4587148 to create a new user and grant privilege and change the user in database.yml

Comment: Well, now I have privilege to create database. I did it. When I run : $ taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 fc password  it returns : Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

```
 kernel_require.rb:133:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions
```

My ruby version was 2.3.0 i just switched into ruby 1.9.3 temporary and this error disappeared

```
taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 user password
```

and now command above works fine so i can migrate sqlite to postgresql with **taps** gem

You need install these gems

```
tilt '1.4.1'
rack '1.0.1'
```

because when you hit command below

```
taps pull postgres://admin:password@localhost/db_development http://user:password@localhost:5000
```

you can see such error

```
 ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using this command. (If it is rails 6)

```
rails db:system:change --to=postgresql
```

See list of other database type below:

```
rails db:system:change --to=mysql, 
rails db:system:change --to=sqlite3, 
rails db:system:change --to=oracle, 
rails db:system:change --to=frontbase, 
rails db:system:change --to=sqlserver, 
rails db:system:change --to=jdbc
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed these steps when I migrated my application to postgres from sqlite3

```
1. Remove or comment sqlite3 gem
2. Add gem "pg" to your gem file and bundle
3. Add your database.yml 
4. bundle exec rake db:setup
```

You should have your postgres server up and running.

Comment: I don't want to loose all my datas stored in my DB. Does it work when you already have datas in your sqlite3 DB ?

Comment: I don't understand how do you transfer the datas from sqlite3 to Postgres with this process ? How and when do you set  up User/password for your Postgres DB ?

Comment: Do you have production data in your database or is it application seed data? If it's not a ton of data, I'd suggest writing seeds for it so you can rebuild that data on the fly as needed. If it's production data, I'm sorry you did that. sqlite3 is really not good for real production data. Check this link for possible tools/scripts to migrate the data itself. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL

Comment: @Florian_CEO when I made this change the application was in development. So I did not care about the data. And yes when I made this change the data is lost. If you are in production I suggest not to go with this approach.

Answer (score -1):

What the errors saying is that your database developement dosen'nt exist. if your want start rails app with pg in developement mode, you have to create the database first with:

```
rake db:create
```

But if you won't to deploy your app and still using it locally without loosing any of tour data, just set sqlite3 to developement and postgres to production:

First, you need to add pg gem to production group in your gemfile  and sqlite3 to developement, so you don't lose any of your data:
 change in your Gemfile from:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
.....
gem 'sqlite3'
.
.
.
```

to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
...
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'

end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
.
.
.
```

Run

```
bundle install
```

Second, uncoment your config.yml production part  that contain sqlite3 configuration and add postgresql config like so:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```