# Rails 5 how to clear or delete production postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-postgresql

I am trying to delete a production database so I can start fresh. When I upgraded to rails 5 from rails 4, it is now protecting the production database from accidental deletion. It shows the following error message when I run `rake db:reset`.

```
/app# rake db:reset
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (1.6ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key", :environment]]
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key", :environment]]
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key", :environment]]
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ProtectedEnvironmentError: You are attempting to run a destructive action against your 'production' database.
If you are sure you want to continue, run the same command with the environment variable:
DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:51:in `check_protected_environments!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:reset => db:drop => db:check_protected_environments
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It says that my adding the environment variable  DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 to the command should work but it does not. I run it and it does nothing.

```
<606723-x9dh4:/app# DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 rake db:reset       
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Appreciate the help!

UPDATE:

My server is deployed using kubernetes. I am guessing that I am not able to reset the database because the server is running.

Comment: can you try using rails instead of rake like `RAILS_ENV=production DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 bin/rails db:reset`

Comment: No luck, just does the same thing.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this it worked for me:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:drop DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
```

in a single line.

Comment: Is there a way to add this to a config file in local environment so we don't need to write it every time in the terminal?

Answer (score 36):

It also happens when you dump production database into local. If you want to delete it on local machine, you will need to set `bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development`, and after `rake db:drop`

Comment: This is the proper way to do this after the import of a production database to your development environment.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had used my heroku production in development for the first time recently (```heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL my_app_name --app my_app_name --remote production```) and didn't realize I would have to alter the way I dropped it. (```rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development; rails db:drop```)

Comment: If you at one point dumped your production DB into your development DB, the `value` in your `ar_internal_metadata` has probably changed to `production`. So you might want to replace it with `development` before running rake commands in your local development environment.

Answer (score 17):

From Heroku's documentation on [Running Rake commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake):

> The db:reset task is not supported. Heroku apps do not have permission to drop and create databases. Use the heroku pg:reset command instead.

So instead of trying to have `rails` or `rake db:reset`, try this:

`heroku pg:reset`

Comment: Just noticed the title doesn't include Heroku, but this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Well, even though this is an old post, but for future reference, you can do

```
    rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

And then

```
    rake db:migrate
```

Comment: yep, that's the way to go if you won't disconnect your db and can rollback your migrations

Comment: Worked like a charm - migrated back my DB to the beginning of time, re-deploying my code then automatically migrated to the latest schema

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when working with a Rails 5.2 application and PostgreSQL database in production.

**Here's how I solved it**:

First, stop every session using the database to avoid [database is being accessed by other users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114185/11793091) error.

```
sudo kill -9 `ps -u postgres -o pid=`
```

Also, log out every connection to the database on the [PGAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) Client if any.

Start the PostgreSQL server, since the kill operation above stopped the PostgreSQL server.

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Drop the database in the production environment appending the production arguments.

```
rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=production DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
```

Create the database in the production environment appending the production arguments.

```
rails db:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

i know, it could be a little late, but, if it fails to drop with standart rails way, u can always use psql like 
`psql --u your_user`

then enter password
type `\l` to list all db.
in my case, psql reject to drop single table, and i create additional db, like 'testdb', typed `\c testdb` to establish connection with it, then type `drop database 'olddb_name';`, then `create database 'olddb_name';` and its done!

Answer (score 1):

It is not working but  you should run commands like this

```
 bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production db:drop DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
```

and when you drop the table you have to create it back.So you will get error if you don't have rights to createdb.Here your asnwer [Postgres permission denied to create database on rake db:create:all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116927/postgres-permission-denied-to-create-database-on-rake-dbcreateall)

when you type `psql` you exit from there by typing `\q`.

Like i said this is not the answer but i hope this will save your time while you are searching. Beacuse i am right there right now. GL&HF

Answer (score 0):

Can you give below a shot?

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:drop
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```

This is an old method, but that's how I used to reset the database to pristine level.